# Cannot cd to a directory returned by an exe program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cd

I have this simple file:

**tags**

```
home C:\Users\rodde
docs C:\Users\rodde\Documents
prev D:\
dt C:\Software\dt
```

The first column contains the *tags*, and the second column contains respective directories. Also, I have a program (`dt.exe`) that expects a tag and prints to `std::cout` a respective directory. For example, `dt.exe docs` will output `C:\Users\rodde\Documents`. Finally, I have a batch script `dt.bat`

```
@echo off

if [%*] == 1 (
    rem Once here, we have no arguments.
    rem Chdir to the previous directory.
    dt.exe prev > directory.tmp
    set DIR=<directory.tmp
    dt.exe --update-prev %cd%
    cd %DIR%
) else if [%1] == [-l] (
    dt.exe -l
) else if [%1] == [-s] (
    dt.exe -s
) else if [%1] == [-L] (
    dt.exe -L
) else if [%1] == [-S] (
    dt.exe -S
) else if [%1] == [-d] (
    dt.exe -d
) else (
    rem Once here, we have a tag, so chdir
    rem to respective directory
    dt.exe %1 > directory.tmp
    set DIR=<directory.tmp
    cd %DIR%
)
```

Unfortunately, this works only every 4th time or so.

What am I missing?

(The source code for `dt.exe` is [here](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/6398d13882a2c1801c4ca034bdb35c6e).)

Comment: `If Not "%~1"=="" dt.exe %~1`

Comment: Please provide a more specific title of your question! the current one is nothing but totally useless! Thank you!

Comment: `if [%*] == 1` will never be fulfilled; I guess you meant `if [%*] == []`. Anyway, the bracket syntax seems to be widely used but is very bad practice; use quotes instead like shown by CatCat: `if "%*"==""`; this protects white-spaces and other special characters. Nevertheless, the `else if` blocks could be avoided by just using `dt.exe %1`...

Comment: The main problem in your code is the fact that you assign a variable (`DIR`) and read it in the same block of code, which requires [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); otherwise, you actually read the value that was present before the whole block is read...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your if statements are incorrectly defined, you don't need all the else statements either.. so as a start:

```
@echo off

if [%*] == [] (
    rem Once here, we have no arguments.
    rem Chdir to the previous directory.
    dt.exe prev > directory.tmp
    set DIR=<directory.tmp
    dt.exe --update-prev %cd%
    cd %DIR%
) else (
     if [%1] == [-l] dt.exe -l
     if [%1] == [-s] dt.exe -s
     if [%1] == [-L] dt.exe -L
     if [%1] == [-S] dt.exe -S
     if [%1] == [-d] dt.exe -d
) else (
    rem Once here, we have a tag, so chdir
    rem to respective directory
    dt.exe %1 > directory.tmp
    set DIR=<directory.tmp
    cd %DIR%
)
```

However, this is very tedious and unwanted. why not simply replace all of the if else with a single statement:

```
dt.exe %~1
```

So we can test by checking if `%~1` is valid or not, if not, exit, if it is, execute:

```
if "%~1"=="" exit || dt.exe %~1
```

Does not matter what your input it, it will run it, unless empty. Obviously you can replace the `exit` with other commands.